# ¿Cómo obtener la ruta del proyecto, sin importar la raiz donde se encuentre dicho archivo en python y luego concatenarlo l nombre de un archivo?

Tags: python, archivo

Tengo una proyecto en Python el cual esta en la ruta D:\Proyectos\Tablero, en este directorio tengo un archivo de Excel "Tablero.xlsm"

Quisiera saber la forma que puedo llamar en python el directorio del proyecto, es decir el directorio actual, y luego concatenarlo al nombre del archivo de excel, con el fin de que me quede una variable con la ruta absoluta.
estoy intentando lo siguiente:

```
ruta_tablero = str(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()))
mrapp = ruta_tablero + '\Tablero.xlsm'
```

pero me genera el siguiente error:

pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ocurrió una excepción.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Lo sentimos, no hemos encontrado D:\Proyectos\Tablero.xlsm. ¿Puede ser que lo haya movido, eliminado o le hayas cambiado el nombre?', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

Comment: tu ruta final queda `\Tablero\Tablero.xlsm`, si en tu carpeta `Tablero` no existe tal archivo pues es correcto, por otra parte no es necesario convertir a string pues ya te lo devuelve como string

Comment: Estás seguro de que el archivo .py y el xlsm están en la misma carpeta? Estas usando Visual Studio Code para ejecutar el script de Python?

Comment: Hola Dante S. si el archivo .xlsm esta en la misma carpeta que el .py

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero me responderias mi segunda pregunta porfa?

Comment: Hola Dante S. discúlpame omití esta parte.  Así es, estoy ejecutado el scrip  en visual studio code

Comment: No hay problema c: Por lo que estoy viendo, tu directorio de trabajo está en "D:/Proyectos"... Creo que esto podría ser un problema del Visual Studio Code. Podrías probar con ejecutar tu script SIN usar dicho editor por favor?

Comment: Hola Dante S. Tienes toda la razon, bajo otro editor no tuve problemas en correr el programa.  Sabes de pronto como puedo arreglar esto cuando apunta al disco d?  Mil gracias por la orientacion.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el método **path.join** del modulo **os** para crear la ruta absoluta que deseas. Con pasar los nombres que conforman la ruta el método creará la ruta por ti. Puedes hacer algo como esto, suponiendo que tu script esta dentro de la carpeta 'Tablero':

```py
import os

mrapp = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"Tablero.xlsm")
```

Comment: Hola Calumrakk, mil gracias por tu respuesta.  Me parece una opcion muy util, pero al ejecutar el lprograma me genera el mismo error .  pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ocurrió una excepción.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Lo sentimos, no hemos encontrado D:\\Proyectos\\Tablero.xlsm. ¿Puede ser que lo haya movido, eliminado o le hayas cambiado el nombre?', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None) es como si omitiera la carpeta del proyecto Tablero.

Comment: Hola, Ruben, parece que estas ejecutando el script desde la carpeta 'Proyectos' y como el archivo esta dentro de la carpeta 'Tablero' no encuentra el archivo. Intenta con esta línea y cuéntame como te va: os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"Tablero","Tablero.xlsm")